# mouse_right click event not working for a panel in winform using c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I am trying to fire the mouse right button click event of a `Panel` and call a function but its not firing. This is my code:

```
private void viewscreen_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        generate_editpanel();
    }
}
```

"viewscreen" is a `Panel`. And my designer code is:

```
// viewscreen
// 
this.viewscreen.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaptionText;
this.viewscreen.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(208, 16);
this.viewscreen.Name = "viewscreen";
this.viewscreen.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(370, 289);
this.viewscreen.TabIndex = 0;
this.viewscreen.MouseClick += 
    new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.viewscreen_MouseClick);
```

Can any one help me?

Comment: check if event will raise without `e.Button == MouseButtons.Right`

Comment: no the viewscreen_MouseClick event is not hitting

Comment: :) hmm, try to check another events like mouseover in panel, do they work

Comment: no, no event is working for that panel i tried that before bcoz that wasn't working so i tried this.. no event is working on that panel

Comment: Can you add code for declaring the this.viewscreen?

Comment: can u explain a little .. its a fixed panel and i am also enabling it

Comment: paste here full code related to this.viewscreen ....if any other controls are there on that panel then those control will not allow the mouse click panel. Top most control event will fire.

Comment: you say you are enabling it, may be it is disabled? paste code, where you are enabling it

Comment: `this.viewscreen = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();`
`private System.Windows.Forms.Panel viewscreen;`

Comment: ` chcgrpbx.Enabled = true;
            VideoPanel.Enabled = true;
            EditPanel.Enabled = true;
            viewscreen.Enabled = true; `
@jesseJames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The video object in your Panel must be covering up the whole area (docked) of the Panel. In that case the event of the panel wont't get fired because all the clicks will take place on the video object.
But if you still wish to fire the event of the panel you can modify the form designer code like this:

```
this.pictureBox1.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.pictureBox1_MouseClick);
this.pictureBox1.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.viewscreen_MouseClick);
```

Here I have docked a PictureBox(pictureBox1) in the panel(viewscreen). And now in the form code you can test like this:

```
private void viewscreen_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, "Right Clicked on Panel");
        }            
    }
 private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(this, "Picture Clicked");
        //this.viewscreen_MouseClick(sender, e);
    }
```

Comment: yeah, but what i saw in last few minutes while solving this problem is that the MouseClick event may doesn't work for Panel, but MouseDown event does and that saved me

Answer (score 0):

paste here full code related to this.viewscreen ....if any other controls are there on that panel then those control will not allow the mouse click panel. Top most control event will fire

Comment: yes i have a video object on that panel ...  that panel acting as a screen .. of my video

Comment: Is that Video object is docked fully on that panel?

Comment: `video = new Video(vpath[0]);
            video.Owner = viewscreen;
            video.Stop();
            viewscreen.Size = new Size(width, height);`
this is wht i am doing

Comment: Is that Video object is docked fully on that panel? if so then panel mouse click event will not fire...

Comment: i dont think its docked any how

Comment: @Drone if Video object is on the panel, if you right click it will fire the Video Object Mouse Click event, No Panel Events will be fired...

Comment: so any solution for that .. dose video object has click event? or should i add another panel?

Comment: Check for Video Object is there any event....if not there then you can achieve the same things with different options like providing a button,context menu,etc.........

Comment: instead of `viewscreen_MouseClick` event it should be `viewscreen_MouseDown`

Answer (score 0):

instead of ...

```
private void viewscreen_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        generate_editpanel();
    }
}
```

using this ...

```
private void viewscreen_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            generate_editpanel();
        }
    }
```

is working for me